# Default header set on @MessageGateway not showing up on the message

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Hey i'm trying to set a default header for multiple methods in my `@MessagingGateway`. All these methods sort of go into the same method channel, so i'm trying to use the method name to determine where the message came from. For assigning the method name to the default header, i'm using the spel expression `#methodName` as per what i found in:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/929

Here's the gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultHeaders={@GatewayHeader(name="statusMethod", expression="#methodName")})
public interface LoggingGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel="logStatusChannel")
    public void logTokenStatus(@Header("pairInfo") PairInfo info, @Payload String status);

    @Gateway(requestChannel="logStatusChannel")
    public void logDataMessageStatus(@Header("pairInfo") PairInfo info, @Payload String status);

}
```

But further down the flow when i try to access the header, the error tells me that it can't find the default header.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 18): Property or field 'statusMethod' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders' - maybe not public?
```

I even tried ditching the default header and adding a header to each of the methods. Even that didn't help. I tried using `#methodString` instead, but it didn't find that either.

Dunno if the java bean i'm using is the exact translation of what i saw in the the xml config in the link.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually you have read the wrong source.
Take a look into the official [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-configuration-annotations):

> The `<header/>` element supports expression as an alternative to value. The SpEL expression is evaluated to determine the value of the header. There is no `#root` object but the following variables are available:
>
> `#args` - an Object[] containing the method arguments
>
> `#gatewayMethod` - the java.reflect.Method object representing the method in the service-interface that was invoked. A header containing this variable can be used later in the flow, for example, for routing. For example, if you wish to route on the simple method name, you might add a header, with expression `#gatewayMethod.name`.

The description of that PR doesn't reflect reality. There is such a [discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/929#discussion-diff-7150482), which led to the target `#gatewayMethod` solution:

> artembilan on Oct 23, 2013 Spring member
>
> Looks like there is no reason to have so much variables around Method. It just enough to have the last one. All others can be extracted via SpEL:
>   expression="#method.name" expression="#method.toString()"
>
> garyrussell on Oct 23, 2013 Spring member
>
> True, but then I don't like methodObject, but we have to keep method as the simple name (we could document it in the migration guide, but I'd rather minimize pain).
>
> Maybe serviceMethod ?
>
> artembilan on Oct 23, 2013 Spring member
>
> Then gatewayMethod
>
> garyrussell on Oct 23, 2013 Spring member
>
> :+1:

By the way. There is no your custom global `statusMethod` header, just because a SpEL `#methodName` returns `null`. So, such a header isn't populated.